# Detect face using active appearance model emguCV

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

I am implementing a face detection application using emguCV (an openCV Wrapper for C#). I decided to use active appearance model (AAM) for face detection . When i searched for active appearance model (AAM) libraries , i was able to find [this](https://code.google.com/p/aam-opencv/) , i want to know whether this library can be using in emguCV ?
Are any other AAM libraries available for emguCV  ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you want face *detection* , not face  *recognition* . right ?

Comment: yes , I just want to detect and get the ROI

Answer (score 0):

AAM is for face recognition. It works bad for detection task. If you need detect face ROI use Viola-Jones detector, it faster and get better results.  Usually AAM applied to ROI detected by Viola-Jones detector (for find face features).

Comment: Thanks for the response , I am currently using haar-Cascades to detect faces , and i am not satisfied with the result and searching for a better way to detect faces... Are there an way to detect face in 3d using single camera ?

Comment: So, I see that you task is 3D pose estimation. In that case yes, you need to find face features, but AAM not the best way, ASM works more stable. AAM more precise if trained for certain person. But in other cases it works worse than ASM. I don't know C# bindings of ASM and AAM, but you can find C++ implementations in http://www.packtpub.com/cool-projects-with-opencv/book book and sources for this book https://github.com/MasteringOpenCV/code (see chapter 6).